# Display the menu on hover in tailwind CSS

Tags: navigation, hover, tailwind-css

I am working on Tailwind UI component navigation, it is functionality require the user to click the button to display the menu, I am trying to get content while simply hovering the menu, instead of use click it, i am working on their codes now, but it gets confusing. can anyone help me out how to do hover?

{/* Flyout menus */}

```
          {navigation.categories.map((category) => (
            <Popover key={category.name} className="flex">
              {({ open }) => (
                <>
                  <div className="relative flex">
                    <Popover.Button
                      className={classNames(
                        open
                          ? 'border-indigo-600 text-indigo-600'
                          : 'border-transparent text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-800',
                        'relative z-10 flex items-center transition-colors ease-out duration-200 text-sm font-medium border-b-2 -mb-px pt-px'
                      )}
                    >
                      {category.name}
                    </Popover.Button>
                  </div>

                  <Transition
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
                    enterFrom="opacity-0"
                    enterTo="opacity-100"
                    leave="transition ease-in duration-150"
                    leaveFrom="opacity-100"
                    leaveTo="opacity-0"
                  >
                    <Popover.Panel className="absolute top-full inset-x-0 text-sm text-gray-500">
                      {/* Presentational element used to render the bottom shadow, if we put the shadow on the actual panel it pokes out the top, so we use this shorter element to hide the top of the shadow */}
                      <div className="absolute inset-0 top-1/2 bg-white shadow" aria-hidden="true" />

                      <div className="relative bg-white">
                        <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-8">
                          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-y-10 gap-x-8 py-16">
                            <div className="col-start-2 grid grid-cols-2 gap-x-8">
                              {category.featured.map((item) => (
                                <div key={item.name} className="group relative text-base sm:text-sm">
                                  <div className="aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1 rounded-lg bg-gray-100 overflow-hidden group-hover:opacity-75">
                                    <img
                                      src={item.imageSrc}
                                      alt={item.imageAlt}
                                      className="object-center object-cover"
                                    />
                                  </div>
                                  <a href={item.href} className="mt-6 block font-medium text-gray-900">
                                    <span className="absolute z-10 inset-0" aria-hidden="true" />
                                    {item.name}
                                  </a>
                                  <p aria-hidden="true" className="mt-1">
                                    Shop now
                                  </p>
                                </div>
                              ))}
                            </div>
                            <div className="row-start-1 grid grid-cols-3 gap-y-10 gap-x-8 text-sm">
                              {category.sections.map((section) => (
                                <div key={section.name}>
                                  <p id={`${section.name}-heading`} className="font-medium text-gray-900">
                                    {section.name}
                                  </p>
                                  <ul
                                    role="list"
                                    aria-labelledby={`${section.name}-heading`}
                                    className="mt-6 space-y-6 sm:mt-4 sm:space-y-4"
                                  >
                                    {section.items.map((item) => (
                                      <li key={item.name} className="flex">
                                        <a href={item.href} className="hover:text-gray-800">
                                          {item.name}
                                        </a>
                                      </li>
                                    ))}
                                  </ul>
                                </div>
                              ))}
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </Popover.Panel>
                  </Transition>
                </>
              )}
            </Popover>
          ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all it would be nice to inform what other components are you using. I see Popover and Transition but have no idea wich exactly are they. Also please inform wich vue version and wich type of API.

Still, you can use

```
@mouseover="event"
@mouseleave="event"
```

and simply call the event to simulate the click.